# Sklearn: get confidence of ridgeclassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I need to get confidence of model in returned answer, because sometimes probabilities looks strange.

I use

```
d = clf.decision_function(s)[0]
probs = np.exp(d) / (1 + np.exp(d))
```

to get probabilities of every class.

Is any way to get confidence of `RidgeClassifier`?

Comment: What looks strange about them?  I often have classifiers become, e.g. overconfident and return essentially one hot vectors as probabilities...

Comment: @Scott I always get high probability like 0.8, but it's incorrect answer. Also I try to use softmax `np.exp(d) / np.sum(np.exp(d))` to get all probabilities, and sum it's probabilities is 1. And I need to avoid some errors so I need in confidence

Comment: The function in your comment (which is the softmax function) to get the answer to sum to 1 is not the function in your question's code?  In any case, the probabilities output by, say, logistic regression are always subject to interpretation.  If you don't like them, scale them.  The term you want is "calibration" e.g. [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) has methods that do this.

Comment: That looks like a sigmoid function. probabilities doesn't look strange, your classifier probably doesn't return a "probability" value. the sigmoid function takes a number between -inf to +inf and puts it between 0 to 1. where sig(0) = 0.5. I have no clue what you're trying to do

Comment: @EranMoshe first I've tried to get probabilities of every class in model and get result with max. But there are many errors where probability more than 0.8. So I need to get confidence of this model, but don't know what methods should I use